# Can Python file write in Linux do partial writes?

Tags: python-3.x

I am running python in a Linux machine.
I wonder if a write() done on a file object returned from open() can write less than the amount of data given?

I know this is the behavior in os.write() but I am not sure if that's the case in file.write() as well or not?

So shall I keep retrying until all data is written? Or is it safe to assume everything is written in case of success?

Comment: If you use `open` as a contextmanager (i.e. `with open(...) as f: f.write(..)`), you are guaranteed that everything has been written _once you have left the context manager_. Alternatively, calling `.close()` should flush all buffers, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. `open()` returns a 'TextIOWrapper'. From its docstring: "Character and line based layer over a BufferedIOBase object, buffer."

Assuming `f = open("/path/to/text.txt", "w")`, calling `f.flush()` will ensure all data currently in the buffer is flushed/written to `"/path/to/text.txt"`.

If line buffering is active (`f.line_buffering == True`), writes ending with a line break are flushed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was never clear to me what open actually returns.  P.S. sorry for my very late response.

Comment: You are welcome. If you work with jupyter, you can execute `?f` to get a lot of information about the file Object. In any interactive environment (including jupyter), `help(f)` does the trick. Also check out the [Python documentation to read and write files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), i.e. the use of `with open('/path/to/file') as f:` for reads and writes that automatically close the files after use and thus ensure complete writes.